# Why am I getting these seemingly random output?

Tags: c, data-structures

I am stuck at a C language problem in which I was supposed to input name and age of players from their respective files and output the same for a specific number of players which will be taken input (OR -1 to exit). The problem has to be solved using structures. I have attached the output I am getting along with the data that the age and name files contained.

Can someone explain to me where I am doing wrong?

Any help in optimisation too will be really helpful. Thanks!

Following is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Cricket_Player_DataBase 
{
    char name[30];
    int score;
    char role[11];
    int age;
    int wickets;
};

int main()
{
    FILE *nf_ptr , *af_ptr; //nf_ptr is pointing to name.txt file | af_ptr is pointing to age.txt file
    
    nf_ptr = fopen("name.txt","r");
    af_ptr = fopen("age.txt","r");
    
    int number_of_players = 0; //will be used to fix the size of array of structures

// following code is used just to count number of players, upto the point where 'HERE' is written

    int temp, border_check = 0;
    
    while((temp = fgetc(af_ptr)) != EOF)
    {
        if(temp == '\n') 
        {
            ++number_of_players;
            border_check = 0;
        }
        else border_check++;
    }
    if(border_check > 0) ++number_of_players;
    
    af_ptr = fopen("age.txt","r");

// HERE
    
    struct Cricket_Player_DataBase players[number_of_players];
    
    int temp_age , zero = 0 ;
    char temp_char[30] , ch ;
    
    for(int i=0; i < number_of_players; ++i)
    {
        temp_age =  fgetc(af_ptr);
        players[i].age = temp_age;
        
        while((ch = fgetc(nf_ptr)) != EOF)
        {
            if(ch == '\n')
            {
                strncpy(players[i].name , temp_char , zero+1);
                zero = 0;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                temp_char[zero] = ch;
                zero++;
            }
        }
    }
    
    int input;
    
    printf("Enter number of players you want to see the data of OR type -1 to exit : ");
    scanf("%d", &input);
    
    if(input > 0)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < input; ++i)
        {
            printf("Data of player #%d is \nName : %s\nAge : %d\n", i+1 , players[i].name , players[i].age);
        }
    }
    
    fclose(nf_ptr);
    fclose(af_ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFW0M.png) I got.

[Name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRG7D.png) file was this.

[Age](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3cRE.png) file was this.

Comment: `if(ch = '\n')` --> `if(ch == '\n')`

Comment: Really sorry about that, but I am still getting the same output. I have corrected this mistake in question though @kaylum

Comment: Are you sure you get **exactly** the same output? Your code has other problems but that should improve the result slightly.

Comment: Yes, at least in my cmd.

Comment: Your while loop is wrong. `i` is never incremented there so it is copying to the same player for every name in the file. Also you don't nul terminate the name so it is not a valid string.

Comment: That's why I have added break statement. Everytime a name is copied, it gets out of while loop and then i is increased. Also, I didn't get what you mean by nul terminate the name.

Comment: Sorry you are right. Missed the break. Nul terminate means you should do `temp_char[zero++]=0` before the `strncpy` to ensure it is a valid C string.

Answer (score 0):

You're opening af_ptr without closing it. It could cause problems. If you want to open the same file again, use function rewind(file) or fclose it and open it again.

Comment: Done, got different output but still some garbage value.

Comment: Emm, i think you need to cast  fgetc to int in temp_age. It could lead to problem and beside that you're scanning only one char and not the whole int (ex. 4 instead of 40)

Comment: And you should get some kind of border for input to not get outside of the array of your struct.

Comment: yes that's why I was getting the wrong output as the age. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have made an assumption that the end of each name and age in your text files is a line feed character '\n'. Assuming you have created your text files in a windows machine, the line endings are `\r\n`, that is - a carriage return character followed by a line feed. Using Hex Editor Neo, here's what your files' contents would look like.

[Your name.txt file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SaMYd.png)
[Your age.txt file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJUcR.png)

Notice the line endings - '0x0d' is a carriage return '\r' and '0x0a' is a line feed '\n'. Modify your program to take this into account.

Read more about line endings here: https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-great-newline-schism/